# error: no match for ‘operator<<’

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, operator-overloading

This is my operator<< implementation:

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, FileDir &obj) {    
out << obj.toString();    
return out;
}
```

I have added this line to my FileDir header file, after the FileDir class declaration:

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, FileDir &obj);
```

In my FileDirTest, in order to test the operator<<, I have the following:

```
assert(cout << t1 == "testFileOne 50kb");
```

(where t1 is a FileDir)

This is the error I get:

```
error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ and ‘FileDir’)
assert(cout << t1 == "testFileOne 50kb");
```

Also, here is the complete header file:

```
 #include <sstream>

class FileDir {

public:
    FileDir();
    FileDir(std::string nameVal, long sizeVal = 4, bool typeVal = false);
    FileDir(const FileDir &obj);
    ~FileDir();            // destructor
    long getSize() const;
    std::string getName() const;
    bool isFile() const;
    std::string rename(std::string newname); 
    long resize(long newsize);
    std::string toString();
    bool operator== (const FileDir &dir1);
    bool operator<(const FileDir &obj);   

private:
    std::string name;
    long size;
    bool type;
};

std::ostringstream& operator<< (std::ostringstream &out, FileDir &obj);
```

This is my toString():

```
std::string FileDir::toString()

{
    std::string whatever;
    std::stringstream converter;
    converter << size;
    converter >> whatever;

std::string combined;

if (type == false) { 
    combined = name + " " + whatever + "kb";
}

if (type == true) {
    combined = name + "/" + " " + whatever + "kb";
}

return combined;
}
```

And this is the part of FileDirTest that causes the error:

```
static void OperatorsTest() {

        FileDir t1("testFileOne", 50, false);
        FileDir t2("testDirectory", 100, true);
        FileDir t3("testFileTwo", 20, false);
        assert(t1 < t2);
        assert(t3 < t2);        

        std::ostringstream oss; 
        oss << t1;
        assert(oss.str() == "testFileOne 50kb");        

    }
```

Comment: The `obj` parameter should probably be a `const` reference.

Comment: And that's definitely not how you test what was printed out.

Comment: Also, what do you the the relative priorities of `<<` and `==` are?  Because `cout` doesn't return a string.

Comment: How would I check for the correct output with cout then?

Comment: Perhaps something like this?

cout << t1;
std::string str = cout.str();
assert(str == "testFileOne 50kb");

Comment: Can't do that with the standard output stream, use [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream).

Comment: As for your problem, you *have* included the header file with the declaration of the function?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes, the header file has definitely been included. Also, do you mean I should replace std::ostream& with std:ostringstream& everywhere it appears?

Comment: I mean that you can't get what was written to  `std::cout`, but you can use a string stream to get a string you can test, and then write the string to `std::cout`. E.g. `std::ostringstream oss; oss << t1; if (oss.str() != "...") { ... } else std::cout << oss.str();`

Comment: So I added:  std::ostringstream oss; oss << t1; assert(oss.str() == "testFileOne 50kb");

Comment: But the error persists.

Comment: Regarding the compiler error, it's impossible to say anything without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I just updated the post to include more details that might help. And thanks for all your help thus far as well! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Turns out that my header file had been compiled previously, so any of the changes I'd been making to it didn't go through. Once I deleted the .gch file, FileDirTest finally compiled.